# The new QT GUI for existing applications will be integrated with the Ayatana overlay scrollbars?

Tags: gui, 12.04, qt, ayatana, overlay-scrollbars

With the last updates in **Ubuntu 12.04** at least two **new GUI in QT** for existing applications are landed: Ubuntu One Control Panel, and Checkbox (the system testing tool).
These new GUIs are pretty good, but they don't include the Ayatana scrollbars like the other GTK applications.
I wonder if it is planned to apply the Ayatana scrollbars also for the QT GUI, or not. I mean, that these new GUIs are a good, but so far they introduce a bit of incoherence in the Unity Desktop experience.
So far, we already have some applications, like Chromium or LibreOffice, that don't recognize the Ayatana scrollbars, but at least, all the rest of the GTK applications are coherent.

Comment: I can betcha that it'll land, but I can't point to a bug report or mailing list post for certain.

Comment: @Vosaxalo - doubtful it will land - according to this blueprint, no progress on this: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-overlay-scrollbars

Comment: @Fossfreedom Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

fossfreedom posted this as a comment, which essentially answers the question:

> doubtful it will land - according to this blueprint, no progress on
>   this:
>   [blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/…](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-overlay-scrollbars)

– [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom)♦ [Mar 5 '12 at 10:50](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108008/the-new-qt-gui-for-existing-applications-will-be-integrated-with-the-ayatana-ove#comment129815_108008)

On its whiteboard (main page), that blueprint currently says:

> From Etherpad:
>
> - issues for current implementation users reported: targetting thumb horizontally and vertically
>
> * fix this by increacing the vertically sensitive area of
>   the overlay-scrollbar
>
> * for the horizontal axis a mouse-friction is introduced
>   (Cimi has test-application available) to help the user hit the
>   thumbb-target-area
>
> - suggestion to extend this also to resizing windows at the edges to make the UI behave more consistently
> - toolkits to target for port: xul (partly uses gtk+), qt (e.g. used by unity-2d), vcl (OpenOffice), swing (java applications), nux (used
>     by unity-3d)
> - [lp:ayatana-scrollbar-qt](/+branch/ayatana-scrollbar-qt) is a first attempt at porting the gtk+-based overlay-scrollbar to qt
>
> ACTIONS-items:
>
> [cimi] share overlay-scrollbar documentation with Qt-developers
>
> [cimi, tsenyk] make overlay-scrollbar behaviour-logic fully abstracted
>   (decouple from current gtk+-implementation)
>
> [tsenyk] use that abstracted logic-library for a first port to Qt
>   (also use as an example to test if the abstraction is good enough)

But even now that it's January '13, there hasn't been much progress yet -- the status is still *Not started* and the direction is *Needs approval*.

[image]